# How can I read a Form in HTML and put the value in Python?

Tags: python, html, variables, flask, webserver

I have a server running on my Raspberry Pi 3 via Python Flask. The server is a web page and it uses HTML only no PHP or JavaScript. **What I want to do is to have a form on the web server like "User Name: [user input here] " and for that variable containing the user input to be read from my Python script**. I have struggled for weeks trying to do so and find alternatives. Someone did say to use PHP to write to a file but PHP doesn't work at all on the web page even this:

```
<html>
<body>
  <?php
    echo "Hello World!";
  ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Context:
I am creating a smart room, I have a red led and yellow led on my raspberry pi connected with GPIO Pins and you can control them with those buttons. I have an NodeMcu ESP8266 controlling the curtain in my room which is why the buttons have open and close curtains. I want to be able to have a form where you enter the time you want the curtains to open and close. I would also use forms for other things like logging in and entering custom requests.

I have tried so many different things I just don't know so I am hoping someone can show me how because everything I have tried does not work.
I am stuck on what to do, please help thank you!

Comment: If you've been trying for weeks, you must have some code. You should show that code, and explain exactly what is going wrong with it. (And no, of course PHP won't work with Flask; you need to write Flask code, ie Python.)

Comment: I have code but that is it to the minimum, I just have the basic Flask things that just create a web page.

Comment: Well *show that code*. How are the "basic Flask things that create a web page" not giving you what you need? What *do* you need?

Comment: Sorry to ask but when adding code as a comment how do you go down a line on StackOverflow? because pressing enter submits the comment rather than going down a line.

Comment: Don't. Edit the question and post the code there.

Answer (score 0):

FINALLY!!!
I have solved it!
It's funny how you always jump to the most complex conclusion when in reality it is something small and simple.

I went on to Python Flasks website and found this, here is a link to people with the same problem:

(Either scroll down to the request object or press CTRL + F and search "request object"

[Python Flask Link - The Request Object"](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/quickstart/)